# Where will a constant string be stored in memory?

Tags: c

sometimes we use this type of code in our c programming.

```
char *p = "Sam";
```

Here the address of constant character string "Sam"  is going to be stored in char pointer p. now here
i want to ask where the Sam is going to be stored ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are constant variables stored in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c)

Comment: @BrianRoach A string literal is not a constant variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify this. Typically the string literal (`"Sam"`) will be stored in the data section, in a read-only page.

As for `p` itself, it depends on whether it is automatic or static.

Comment: where automatic and global are stored?

Comment: @Mr.32 The automatic variables are stored on the stack. The "global" or static variables are stored in `data` (or maybe `bss`).

Comment: On which architecture are there read-only pages to a `data` section?  On Linux/ELF, string literals get stored with other read-only non-code data in the `rodata` section, which is in the same segment as `text`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think on x86 any page can be mapped read-only ?

Comment: @cnicutar: protections are set per section on ELF systems (technically, per program-header/segment, the `.text` and `.rodata` sections will tipically share a single `PT_LOAD` program header, see the output of `readelf -l`).

Answer (score 10):

The string "Sam" will usually be stored in global memory in the same region as the global constants.

However, if you did this:

```
char p[] = "Sam";
```

Then it would be on the stack instead. (as an array initializer)