# Crashing when trying to modify constant variable through a pointer

Tags: c

I got a program crash when I am trying to modify constant variable through a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int x = 5;

void changeX(int *x)
{
    (*x) = 20;
    printf("%d", (*x));
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Jelele");
    changeX((int *)&x);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it isn't a good practice and there is no need to make such that ... I am just testing something ...

My question is:

Why program crashes ?!

Comment: Short answer: it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Rather we were expecting a question, `Why program is not crashing?`. You're just lucky. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change where the pointer `x` points to, but as the integer `x` is constant, its value cannot obviously be changed by definition.

Answer (score 2):

```
static const int x = 5;
```

This is a constant variable stored in read-only location so when you try to write to this location then you see a crash.

Like

```
(*x) = 20; /* This is UB */
```

Check the below link:

[Where are constant variables stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c)