# Why the location pointed by a pointer to const is assignable by other variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I have written this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     int b = 15;
     const int *foo = &b;
     //b = 20;
     *foo = 20;
     printf("%d", *foo);
     return 0;
}
```

This means that the location that `foo` is pointing to cannot change. That means `b` cannot change . But when I uncomment the line `b = 20`. It doesn't show any error and I get the output `20` . While in this piece of code I get this error

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:15:10: error: assignment of read-only location '*foo'
      *foo = 20;
```

If `*foo` that is `b` is read only location, why can I change its value `b = 20`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890846/4824627) which I believe will help you understand why this is doing what it is doing

Comment: You can't use `foo` to change what it points at.  There's nothing to stop you from changing what's pointed at by other legitimate mechanisms. Using `b` is a legitimate mechanism to modify the location pointed at by `foo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char \* const and const char \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Comment: Please read the whole question !

Comment: @MikeMB; No, its not.

Comment: @haccks Constant variables are stored in write-protected region of the stack segment . Stack because it is declared in the main() function !

Comment: @PradeepKumar *is* there a write-protected region of the stack segment? If so, it would need to be many fragmented regions of the typical stack frame (in some implementation). My understanding is it's an instruction to the compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c

Comment: I dont know much but this region must be existing till the time of execution of the function then cleaned out along with other local variables !

Comment: C does not mandate any physical hardware or even a stack.

Comment: It has got a stack section in main memory when the program is loaded there for supporting recursion !

Comment: Yes, but C says nothing about physical write-protection, segments or stacks.

Answer (score 8):

What does

```
 int b=15;
 const int* foo=&b;
```

mean?

It means,

- `b` is a modifiable `int` object.
- `&b` has type `int *`. The declaration for `foo` converts `&b` to type `const int *`. This is a valid qualification conversion.
- `int` object pointed by `foo` must not be modified using `foo`.

The above qualification conversion does not invalidates the declaration of `b`, i.e. it still is *modifiable*. `b` can still be used to update its value but `*foo` can't be used.

*Think `const` as a promise*. You promised the compiler that you will not change the value at the location pointed by `foo`, but no one is stopping you to break that promise by changing that value at that location by other means.

Comment: That is the question . foo points to b . I can set it as b=20 and I dont get any error !

Comment: You can't use `foo` to change what it points at.  There's nothing to stop you from changing what's pointed at by other legitimate mechanisms. Using `b` is a legitimate mechanism to modify the location pointed at by `foo`.

Comment: b is just the name given to the value stored in memory (location in memory) . The error says that is read only . How can we change its value then ? Sorry but I am not getting it !

Comment: @PradeepKumar: We can see that you're not getting it.  What's hard is working out why you're not getting it. That `foo` is a pointer to a constant value means that you can't use `foo` to change what it points at. But `b` is not constant. It can be changed. It just can't be changed using `foo`.

Comment: @PradeepKumar; I changed the answer and explained it further. Read it again.

Comment: On Xcode it says this "Read-Only variable is not assignable "

Comment: @PradeepKumar; There is a bar that says "Alcohol will be served to 18+ only". Now think the location of `b` as a bar. `b` is 18+ and is allowed to go there and do whatever it wants. `foo` on the other hand is allowed to go their but restricted to not have alcohol. If it will ask for alcohol then it will be reminded that *"Alcohol will be served to 18+ only"*.

Comment: @PradeepKumar; Yes. It is misleading.

Comment: Why they call it pointer to a constant when we change it by other means !

Comment: @PradeepKumar; it is to inform the compiler that you will not modify the value by using that particular mean.

Answer (score 7):

I think chqrlie is right when he says that the error message "assignment of read-only location '*foo'" is misleading. Actually, `const int *foo` (i.e. a pointer defined as pointing to a `const int`) does not mean that the memory addressed by the pointer is or becomes immutable per se; it just means that the memory addressed by the pointer must not be changed *through this pointer*; it might, however, be changed in other ways. You could define, for example a second pointer `int *foo2 = &b` through which you may change the value addressed by `foo2`.

So you may think of the pointer as being a separate view to a value at a particular memory address, and one may declare the view as read-only or not. This does, however, not effect whether the value at the particular memory address per se is immutable or not:

```
int main()
{
    int b=15;  // b is mutable
    const int* foo=&b; // *foo is immutable; b remains mutable
    int *foo2=&b; // *foo2 is mutable
    b=20;  // allowed, since b is mutable
    *foo=20; // not allowed, since "*foo" is immutable, even if the value to which it points (i.e. b) would be mutable
    *foo2=20; // allowed, since "*foo2" is mutable

    return 0;
}
```

Though not asked, the other way round, you actually may define a *value* as being immutable, and this value must then not be altered in any way; if you somehow manipulated the value by writing to its memory address, the behaviour is undefined:

```
const int c = 15; // c is immutable
int* bar = &c; // warning: discards const qualifier
printf("%d\n", c);
*bar = 20;  // undefined behaviour from here on; modifying a const value is not allowed.
printf("%d\n", c); // undefined behaviour; good chance that it still prints 15, because a compiler might have relied on the fact that c is 15 and immutable
printf("%d\n", *bar); // undefined behaviour; probably printing 20?
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can we have two separate views of the main memory !

Comment: You may have as many pointers as you want, all pointing the the same address of main memory, if you like.

Comment: @PradeepKumar a pointer is simply a variable that holds the address of something else as its value. You can have many pointers all holding the same address (pointing to the same something else). "*views*" may not be the best word, but it accurately describes your ability to view the same bits in memory through multiple pointers if they all point at those bits.

Answer (score 3):

No, `const int* foo = &b;` doesnt mean you cant change `b`, it means that you cant dereference this pointer and change value of dereferenced pointer like this

```
*foo = 20;
```

---

You cant say with `const` that some piece of memory is unmodificable for all. You can say that only that `const` variable cant change this piece of memory, so this operation (if `b` hasnt `const` modifier) is perfectly valid even if you have const pointer pointing to `b`.

```
 b=20;
```

Comment: @Filip Kočica IMO it is "T" - word question

Comment: @PradeepKumar: the error message says `*foo` is a read only location because `foo` is defined as pointing to a location that should not be changed via this pointer. The error message is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @chqrlie: good point, the error message is misleading and likely to be the root cause for OP's misinterpretation of the meaning of the code.

Comment: there is a difference between the pointer declaration and object declaration. The pointer cant be used to change the referenced object. The object itself can be changed, but not via the const pointer

Comment: The point here is that pointer to non-const can be seamlesslly converted to pointer to a const of same type. This is interpreted just as intent NOT to modify the value thru this pointer. The original lvalue, of course, is not affected by adding a new pointer to it and remains writable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant pointer to not constant object declare it:

```
 T * const ptr = &t
```

Where `T` is the type of the object and `t` is the object itself

Comment: That is not what I am asking !

Comment: Please Kumar stop yelling :D

Comment: So learn how to ask questions. `Constant Pointers` means constant pointers not pointers to the constant objects. Blame yourself and appreciate that someone has wasted time yo answer your question

Comment: I admit my mistake . But you should have read the whole question and suggested the edit . Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is after declaring the pointer as

```
const int *foo = &b;
```

you cant use *foo as a L-value because this code also gives the same error

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
     int a=10,b = 15;
     const int *foo = &b;
     foo=&a; //assigning foo the address of a
     *foo=30; // Again here you cant use *foo
     printf("%d", *foo);
     return 0;
}
```