# where is const stored in the memory layout when declared as local or global in C

Tags: c, memory, layout, constants

Does a variable declared locally  int const found in the stack and globally int const found in data segment read-only area.

Comment: A local `const` variable should still have automatic storage (which is probably stack) like normal variables, but it is still read-only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are constant variables stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576489/where-are-constant-variables-stored-in-c)